# How to get UIImage(ImageURL) height and width without converting to NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, nsdata

In my project i need to show the different sizes of images in zig-zag fashion. so, i converted the uiimages(url) which are coming from service to `NSData` and then i get the uiimage. my code is

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[_result objectAtIndex:i ] valueForKey:@"PImage"]];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

so i can get the image size(width and height), But my problem is according to the image size, i need to create `UIView`,  this code is works fine for me, but it is taking too much of time(almost 25 sec) to load 8 images. i figured converting `UIImage` to `NSData` is taking time. Is there any way to get the image size(width and height) without converting it into `NSData`

Thanks for spending time for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can get image properties without actually loading whole image data from disk using ImageIO framework:

```
@import ImageIO;
...

NSURL *imageURL = … // Init URL somehow
CGImageSourceRef imgSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)url, NULL);
NSDictionary* imageProps = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary*) CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imgSource, 0, NULL);

NSLog(@"%@", imageProps);
CFRelease(imgSource);
```

Image width and height will be stored in dictionary under `PixelHeight` and `PixelWidth` keys (tested with png image, may be other image formats will use different keys)

Comment: LET ME CHECK THIS ONE

Comment: "CGImageSourceRef" this will take time same as NSData

Comment: This is taking time to extract the size of the image. Can you suggest something else.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting url to data and to `UIImage`, Use  [EGOImageView](https://github.com/enormego/EGOImageLoading/tree/master/EGOImageView) OR  [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView). You can simply pass the URL to them. Again setFrame based on size of the image.